# BackBarButton won't display correct title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, backbarbuttonitem

I am trying to set my backButton to a simple "<" like this:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.Plain, target:nil, action:nil)
print(self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title)
```

The printing will display "", but running my app on the simulator will always display the title of the previous VC.

Though I tested

```
 navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:0.60, green:0.60, blue:0.60, alpha:1.0)
```

will change the button's color.

**Note:**

I am pushing from a `UIViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`
to just a `UIViewController`

Comment: Please check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide the `backbarbutton` title through out your app,right?

- Then this trick may help you in achieving that.

  **Swift:**

  ```
  UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -100), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
  ```

  **Objective C:**

  ```
  [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -100)
                                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  ```

Add the above code in your `appdelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`,we are pushing the title out of the frame(hidden) :p.

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"<", style:.Plain, target:nil, action:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

In objective c use following code in pushing controller:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"   " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];                                                     
[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:ARROW_BACK_ICON];
```

Do not use "" title for back button use "          " title for back button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Select your Main.storyboard -> Click `Hide Document Outline`-> Choose your `UIViewController`-> `Select Navigation Item` -> Select `Show the attributes inspector`-> Back button textfield with one space `Back button = " "`

OR

**EDITED**

```
let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    viewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = item
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Can't access it, since I don't have a UINavigationController

Comment: Please check my Edited answer.