# Remove back button text from inherited navigation bar Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I want to know if its possible to remove the navigation bar back button text from an ***inherited*** navigation bar. Presently my navigation bar shows "< ControllerName". I want to simply show the "<" back icon. I would also like to know how to show "< Back", and how to remove it completely.

I understand I could do this by adding a bar button item to the storyboard, however is there an easier way to do it?

Note, this code does not work:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)
```

Comment: Please check this my answer : - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39368022/3515115

Comment: Try this self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = " "

Comment: When trying to set navigation bar button items in the storyboard do I need to embed the secondary controller into a navigation view controller? I cant seem to add bar button items to the view controller where the navigation bar is inferred.

Comment: Working solution: refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48801613/3976183

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You better custom back button for this task.

but You also can do it in other ways. Ex: You have `ViewController1`, and `ViewController2` (You push `ViewController2` from `ViewController1`)

**ViewController1**

```
public class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    override public func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.title = "viewcontroller1 title"
    }

}
```

**ViewController2**

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // get previous view controller and set title to "" or any things You want
        if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
            let previousVC: UIViewController? = viewControllers.count >= 2 ? viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2] : nil; // get previous view
            previousVC?.title = "" // or previousVC?.title = "Back"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. this worked really well. I tried a few other examples, but none were as smooth in the transition between view controllers as this.

Comment: It replaces the back navigation button with text "Back", but it also changes the page title with "Back" text. Only Navigation button text should change and not the page title. ;(

Comment: @NGR did U write code to change previous controller title? like in my answer ViewController1 code.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work for you.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution suggested by @Prashant will remove the back button from navigation bar.
To remove the title, use following:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```